# FTP.exe, команда MDELETE - удаление по маске

Tags: windows, cmd, ftp

В каталоге FTP-сервера имеется набор файлов, имена которых соответствуют шаблону

```
prefix_suffix.txt
```

причём `prefix` у всех файлов одинаков, а `suffix` различается, в том числе длиной (формально - максимально возможная длина не ограничена).

Задача - удалить все файлы, кроме тех, у которых `suffix` имеет длину в 1 символ. Операция должна выполняться штатными средствами операционной системы из BAT/CMD файла.

Решаема ли задача стандартными средствами/командами, доступными в штатном клиенте Windows FTP.exe (либо иными штатными средствами операционной системы) в неинтерактивном режиме?

На текущий момент используется следующий фортель - запускается FTP.EXE с управляющим файлом, в котором после установления соединения сначала к себе копируются указанные файлы (по маске `prefix_?.txt`), потом удаляются все, потом скопированные возвращаются обратно.

Хотелось бы изобрести более изящный метод.

PS. Использование нештатных инструментов для работы с FTP, а также более продвинутых скриптовых средств (VBS/JS/PS) - не рассматривается.

Comment: А почему "только штатными средствами"? Это академический интерес? P.S. Ответ видел, плюсанул.

Comment: @donRumata *А почему "только штатными средствами"?* А очень просто. На произвольной системе наличие использованных нештатных средств - не гарантировано, и для работоспособности решения их необходимо установить (для допускающих - хотя бы скопировать), тогда как решение, использующее только штатные средства, заработает сразу.

Comment: Ну так всё равно на произвольной системе этот скрипт должен как-то оказаться. Какая разница - закопировать только `ftp.cmd` или `ftp.cmd+ftp_on_steroids.exe`? А. И почему PS - не штатная функция?

Comment: @donRumata *Какая разница - закопировать только ftp.cmd или ftp.cmd+ftp_on_steroids.exe?* Копирование одного небольшого текстового файла попроще будет. Да хоть распечатку передавай - всё равно сработает. *почему PS - не штатная функция?* Штатная, не спорю. Но если возникнет надобность внести мелкие изменения (или сотворить аналог по образу и подобию) - с CMD и обезьяна справится, а вот PS требует какой-никакой квалификации.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Задача решена. Правильная команда, выполняющая указанную операцию:

```
mdel prefix_??*.txt
```

---

PS. Указанный способ применим только в случае, если есть за что "зацепиться".

По условию нужно удалять то, что имеет 2 и более символов - именно такая постановка и сбивала с толку. На самом деле надо было учесть ещё и 4 конечных символа, трактуемых как расширение. Именно за них и можно "зацепиться". Скажем, если бы расширения не было (т.е. файлы бы соответствовали шаблону `suffix_prefix`), указанный способ был бы неприменим. Однако если было бы заведомо известно, например, что `prefix` гарантированно содержит некий определённый символ или группу символов (ну, например, символ `X`), задача решалась бы парой шаблонов `prefix_??*X*` + `prefix_?X*`, а если бы этот определённый символ или группа были в конце, то  одним шаблоном `prefix_??*X`.

Иными словами, в шаблонной подгруппе подстановки `?*` символ знака вопроса работает по-разному в зависимости от того, есть ли после звезды хотя бы один не-шаблонный символ. Если нет - знак вопроса работает как "ноль либо один символ", а вот если есть - как "строго один символ". Это поведение отличается от того, как используется данный символ подстановки командным процессором CMD.EXE, который в любом случае использует вариант "ноль либо один символ" - во всяком случае, у FTP-сервера на маршрутизаторе Mikrotik (т.е. в RouterOS). Предполагаю, что это будет верно для всех FTP на *nix-подобных ОС, и не будет верно для штатного FTP-сервера под Windows.